# Ubuntu File System for Backup Server

Tags: mass-storage

I'm setting up an Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS server as an online backup server. I have 3rd party software which I will be installing on the server which will take care of the backups.

My question is, I will have around 15TB of space where the data will be stored, and am unsure of which file system would be best suited, Ext4 / JFS etc...?

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

EXT4 is the standard Linux filesystem. It is stable and works well on servers. It seems to be the best choice.